# Konsole won't work!

Tags: 12.10, konsole

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 wubi, and Konsole using `sudo apt-get install konsole` and it installed fine, but when i tried to open it, it does nothing! I tried to reinstall it, multiple times, but the problem remains. Can anyone help me???

[edit]: I forgot, konsole is working in Kate!!!

Comment: Please explain "does nothing". Does it open the terminal window for you or not? What happens when you run `konsole` from another terminal?

Comment: it won't even open, like there is no program installed. that doesn't work to.

Comment: Try to run `konsole` through your favorite terminal. It will give you a log if it crashes. Post it here. Also, did you try Guake?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be something many people have encountered.

A simple workaround is to start any other terminal and there enter:

> $ /usr/bin/konsole

(once konsole opens you can close the other terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see logs. Maybe you'll see errors messages in Xorg log or syslog

Comment: don't know how to do that :(

Comment: Open Terminal and type: cd /var/log and there you can see content of logs by typing: tailf Xorg.0.log or tailf syslog

Comment: there is only samo data with comm="chrome", nothing else.

Comment: You restarted system after installation of Konsole ? Or you typed sudo ldconfig ?

Comment: I tried to restart, but didn't help at all.